# How to use Filter Store by several items

Tags: python, simpy

I am using simpy to model of manufacturing equipment. The equipment need to make a product using some specified materials. I tried to model this using FilterStore as shown in the following code.

```
import simpy


class Material:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self,env):
        self.env = env
        self.inputs  = simpy.FilterStore(env)

    def run(self):
        mat = [ self.inputs.get(lambda i: i.name == itemname ) for itemname in ["mat1","mat2","mat4"] ]
        res = yield self.env.all_of(mat)
        print([res.events[i]._value.name for i in range(len(res.events))])


def input_materials(env,m):
    for i in range(5):
        m.inputs.put(Material( "mat"+str(i) ))
        m.inputs.put(Material( "mat"+str(i) ))
        m.inputs.put(Material( "mat"+str(i) ))
        yield env.timeout(1)


env = simpy.Environment()
machine = Machine(env)

env.process(machine.run())
env.process(input_materials(env,machine))
env.run()
```

The above code is output as follows.

```
['mat4', 'mat4', 'mat4']
```

I want to get [mat1,mat2,mat4], but the above code all gets mat4.
We have confirmed that the results are as expected if I do not use variable, itemname, and code it separately as follows.

```
    def run(self):
        m1 =  self.inputs.get(lambda i: i.name == "mat1" )
        m2 =  self.inputs.get(lambda i: i.name == "mat2" )
        m4 =  self.inputs.get(lambda i: i.name == "mat4" )
        res = yield self.env.all_of([m1,m2,m4])
        print([res.events[i]._value.name for i in range(len(res.events))])
```

How should I code this? Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subtle.
The itemname in you lambda is the same itemname used in the `for` statement
but, the lambda does not get executed till after `for` statement is done,
meanning when the lambdas finally do run they are all using the same itemname variable from the `for` statement with the `for` statement's last for loop assignment of mat4.
This is also know as a enclosure which can be quite useful

To fix this your lambda needs a local itemname variable

update

```
mat = [ self.inputs.get(lambda i: i.name == itemname ) for itemname in ["mat1","mat2","mat4"] ]
```

to

```
mat = [ self.inputs.get(lambda i,itemname=itemname: i.name == itemname ) for itemname in ["mat1","mat2","mat4"] ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Its working perfectly!!